# How to write C++ getters and setters

Tags: c++, getter-setter, c++-faq

If I need to write a setter and/or getter for I write it like this:

```
struct X { /*...*/};

class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    void set_x(X value)
    {
        x_ = value;
    }
    X get_x()
    {
        return x_;
    }
};
```

However I have heard that this is the *Java style* of writing setters and getters and that I should write it in C++ style. Moreover I was told it is ineficient and even incorrect. What does that mean? How can I write the setters and getters in C++?

---

**Assume the need for getters and/or setters is justified**. E.g. maybe we do some checks in the setter, or maybe we write only the getter.

There has been a lot of chatter about not needing getters and setters. While I agree with most of what's been said here, I still avocate for the need to know how to idiomatically write such methods because there are legitimate reasons where getters and setters are the right solution. They might not look at first glance as a setter or getter but they are, or at least the pattern for writing them applies.

E.g.:

- Getting the size of a vector. You don't want to expose a data member, because it needs to be read only.
- Getters and setters don't need to just expose a data member. Think about getting and setting an element of an array. There is logic there, you can't just expose a data member, there is no data member to expose in the first place. It's still a getter/setter pair you can't avoid:

  ```
  class Vector
  {
      void set_element(std::size_t index, int new_value);
      int get_element(std::size_t index);
  };
  ```

  Knowing the C++ idiomatic way of writing getters and setters will allow me to write the above `get_element`/`set_element` in a C++ idiomatic way.

Comment: why not just make that a public data member

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf last paragraph: "assume the need for getters and setters is justified  e.g. maybe we do some checks in the setters, or maybe we write only the getter)." The question is about how to write one once you have established you need to write one.

Comment: In that case the code in the question is OK with three small changes: (1) *usability*, add `const` to the getter; (2) *readability* of client code, remove the `get_` prefix, and (3) *efficiency*, instead of `x_ = value; ` do `x_ = move( value );`.

Comment: You generally don't need to include the word `get_` or `set_`. They can [both be named `x()`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/373535/126524)

Comment: @Caleth yeah... read the answer ...

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was. After reading the answers, I don't know what they solved.

Comment: @PasserBy const correctness is a big issue. You cannot get the property x on a const object, although you really should.

Comment: What you (and others) find appealing about get'/set'ers quickly becomes drudgery at only slightly larger field counts.  In the systems I have worked, field counts are closer to 100 (not 10).   What do the 400+ functions buy you?   Get/Set'rs do _not_ scale.  I avoid.

Comment: @2785528 getters and setters and not always justified. I do not contest that. They are sometimes not understood and abused. That being said sometimes they are rightly justified. This post is not about when and why to use them.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two distinct forms of "properties" that turn up in the standard library, which I will categorise as "Identity oriented" and "Value oriented". Which you choose depends on how the system should interact with `Foo`. Neither is "more correct".

Identity oriented

```
class Foo
{
     X x_;
public:
          X & x()       { return x_; }
    const X & x() const { return x_; }
}
```

Here we return a *reference* to the underlying `X` member, which allows both sides of the call site to observe changes initiated by the other. The `X` member is visible to the outside world, presumably because it's identity is important. It may at first glance look like there is only the "get" side of a property, but this is not the case if `X` is assignable.

```
 Foo f;
 f.x() = X { ... };
```

Value oriented

```
class Foo
{
     X x_;
public:
     X x() const { return x_; }
     void x(X x) { x_ = std::move(x); }
}
```

Here we return a *copy* of the `X` member, and accept a *copy* to overwrite with. Later changes on either side do not propagate. Presumably we only care about the *value* of `x` in this case.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where each type of property is used in the standard library?

Comment: @KarlNicoll I've got a related answer [at Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373532/how-is-usually-named-a-non-const-getter#373535) that has examples

Comment: i suppose the difference between "identity" and "value oriented" is whether data is actually encapsulated. Only in the second `Foo` one coudl for example count how often `x` was modified, while in the first the "getters" can only do things that are optional for the caller, like eg `at` vs direct access

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sometimes you don't want encapsulated. `std::vector` would be quite obnoxious if you couldn't reference the elements.

Comment: In the "identity oriented" case, is there any advantage of this implementation over simply making `x_` public?

Comment: @luator not hugely

Answer (score 41):

Over the years, I've come to believe that the whole notion of getter/setter is usually a mistake. As contrary as it may sound, a public variable is normally the correct answer.

The trick is that the public variable should be of the correct type. In the question you've specified that either we've written a setter that does some checking of the value being written, or else that we're only writing a getter (so we have an effectively `const` object).

I would say that both of those are basically saying something like: "X is an int. Only it's not really an int--it's really something sort of like an int, but with these extra restrictions..."

And that brings us to the real point: if a careful look at X shows that it's really a different type, then define the type that it really is, and then create it as a public member of that type. The bare bones of it might look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class checked {
    T value;
    std::function<T(T const &)> check;

public:
    template <class checker>
    checked(checker check) 
        : check(check)
        , value(check(T())) 
    { }

    checked &operator=(T const &in) { value = check(in); return *this; }

    operator T() const { return value; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, checked const &c) {
        return os << c.value;
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, checked &c) {
        try {
            T input;
            is >> input;
            c = input;
        }
        catch (...) {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        }
        return is;
    }
};
```

This is generic, so the user can specify something function-like (e.g., a lambda) that assures the value is correct--it might pass the value through unchanged, or it might modify it (e.g., for a saturating type) or it might throw an exception--but if it doesn't throw, what it returns must be a value acceptable for the type being specified.

So, for example, to get an integer type that only allows values from 0 to 10, and saturates at 0 and 10 (i.e., any negative number becomes 0, and any number greater than 10 becomes 10, we might write code on this general order:

```
checked<int> foo([](auto i) { return std::min(std::max(i, 0), 10); });
```

Then we can do more or less the usual things with a `foo`, with the assurance that it will always be in the range 0..10:

```
std::cout << "Please enter a number from 0 to 10: ";
std::cin >> foo; // inputs will be clamped to range

std::cout << "You might have entered: " << foo << "\n";

foo = foo - 20; // result will be clamped to range
std::cout << "After subtracting 20: " << foo;
```

With this, we can safely make the member public, because the type we've defined it to be is really the type we want it to be--the conditions we want to place on it are inherent in the type, not something tacked on after the fact (so to speak) by the getter/setter.

Of course, that's for the case where we want to restrict the values in some way. If we just want a type that's effectively read-only, that's much easier--just a template that defines a constructor and an `operator T`, but not an assignment operator that takes a T as its parameter.

Of course, some cases of restricted input can be more complex. In some cases, you want something like a relationship between two things, so (for example) `foo` must be in the range 0..1000, and `bar` must be between 2x and 3x `foo`. There are two ways to handle things like that. One is to use the same template as above, but with the underlying type being a `std::tuple<int, int>`, and go from there. If your relationships are really complex, you may end up wanting to define a separate class entirely to define the objects in that complex relationship.

#### Summary

Define your member to be of the type you really want, and all the useful things the getter/setter could/would do get subsumed into the properties of that type.

Comment: One newbie question: why doesn't the constructor for `checker` accept `std::function<T(T const &)>`, but instead uses `template <class checker>`?

Comment: Perhaps, for simple stuff, getters and setters are a mistake - adding more complexity than is needed, before there's any demand to do so, so you're just opening up a new source for error without any immediate benefit. But consider multi-threaded code, where you need to defend variables from the "multiple update" problem or wrap them in a critical section. At that point, getters and setters become the easy route, that doesn't require demanding specific usage patterns (e.g. "you must lock this before you can call this" type rules). Doing it early is a mistake, but it has good and valid use too.

Comment: @Bob In my opinion, for multithreading something like I've shown above with the `checked` class is the easy route--both easy to write and (contrary to explicit getters/setters) easy and clean to use.

Comment: Agreeing with the redundancy of most getters/setters, but "If your relationships are really complex, you may end up wanting to define a separate class entirely to define the objects in that complex relationship" feels like _the actual starting point_ to me: quite often we're already in that class, and for trying to address that complexity (interdependencies) aren't getters/setters just the straightforward things to do, instead of deferring that "handling of complexity" into yet another layer of abstractions/complexities?

Comment: @Sz.: Without seeing a concrete example, it's hard to say. I suppose it's possible it might justify a `setter`/`getter`, but if so I haven't seen it yet...

Answer (score 37):

This is how I would write a generic setter/getter:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    X&       x()        { return x_; }
    const X& x() const  { return x_; }
};
```

I will try to explain the reasoning behind each transformation:

The first issue with your version is that instead of passing around values you should pass const references. This avoids the needless copying. True, since `C++11` the value can be moved, but that is not always possible. For basic data types (e.g. `int`) using values instead of references is OK.

So we first correct for that.

```
class Foo1
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    void set_x(const X& value)
//             ^~~~~  ^
    {
        x_ = value;
    }

    const X& get_x()
//  ^~~~~  ^
    {
        return x_;
    }
};
```

Still **there is a problem with the above solution**. Since `get_x` does not modify the object it should be marked `const`. This is part of a C++ principle called *const correctness*.

The above solution will not let you get the property from a `const` object:

```
const Foo1 f;

X x = f.get_x(); // Compiler error, but it should be possible
```

This is because `get_x` not being a const method cannot be called on a const object. The rational for this is that a non-const method can modify the object, thus it is illegal to call it on a const object.

So we make the necessary adjustments:

```
class Foo2
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    void set_x(const X& value)
    {
        x_ = value;
    }

    const X& get_x() const
//                   ^~~~~
    {
        return x_;
    }
};
```

The above variant is correct. However in C++ there is another way of writting it that is more C++ ish and less Java ish.

There are two things to consider:

- we can return a reference to the data member and if we modify that reference we actually modify the data member itself. We can use this to write our setter.
- in C++ methods can be overloaded by consteness alone.

So with the above knowledge we can write our final elegant C++ version:

#### Final version

```
class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    X&       x()        { return x_; }
    const X& x() const  { return x_; }
};
```

As a personal preference I use the new trailing return function style. (e.g. instead of `int foo()` I write `auto foo() -> int`.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    auto x()       -> X&       { return x_; }
    auto x() const -> const X& { return x_; }
};
```

And now we change the calling syntax from:

```
Foo2 f;
X x1;

f.set_x(x1);
X x2 = f.get_x();
```

to:

```
Foo f;
X x1;

f.x() = x1;
X x2 = f.x();
```

```
const Foo cf;
X x1;

//cf.x() = x1; // error as expected. We cannot modify a const object
X x2 = cf.x();
```

#### Beyond the final version

For performance reasons we can go a step further and overload on `&&` and return an rvalue reference to `x_`, thus allowing moving from it if needed.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;

public:
    auto x() const& -> const X& { return x_; }
    auto x() &      -> X&       { return x_; }
    auto x() &&     -> X&&      { return std::move(x_); }

};
```

---

Many thanks for the feedback received in comments and particularly to StorryTeller for his great suggestions on improving this post.

Comment: A simple setter should accept its argument by value and move from that to handle temporaries better.

Comment: Why is your getter giving a reference?  You are breaking encapsulation by doing so.  even passing out a `const&` is a problem as I can cast the constness away and now I have direct access to the member.

Comment: @Nathan If you are saying something breaks encapsulation but you're using `const_cast` to do so your argument has little value. There's a whole lot more you can do to break encapsulation even if your getter didn't return a const reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver if you cast the constness away you are doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @bolov Why?  It is perfectly legal to cast constness away from something that isn't const.

Comment: @bolov - I do understand that. Which is why I focused on what I found *confusing*. I consider myself fairly well-versed in C++, how would a novice handle it?

Comment: @NathanOliver but how do you know that a `const Foo &` is bound to a non-const `Foo`?

Comment: @NathanOliver legal (in the specified case) yes. But you shouldn't do it. If I give you a const reference there is a reason for that. You shouldn't cast away the reference (although it might be legal). Plus you don't know if the data member is const which would make it UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller I understand your point about being confusing. I ... don't know to structure it in a better way. And I briefly touched about references in the first paragraph.

Comment: I deleted my comments now, since you did some extensive editing. IMO, the answer could benefit from keeping trailing return types until the end. Since they really are mostly a stylistic point in the current explanation. I imagine novices would find that to be needless complexity to their emerging ability to parse C++ declarations. It doesn't really add anything to the other valid points.

Comment: You know, another point to consider, since you touched on move semantics, is that one can overload member functions on ref qualifiers too. So we can have `auto x() && -> X&& { return std::move(x_); }` and allow that efficiency we supposedly gave up on when starting.

Comment: Doesn't this violate one of the criteria of the question? *"e.g. maybe we do some checks in the setters"* AFAICT this doesn't work for a non-const getter/setter `X& x()` which would allow `Foo:x_` to be reassigned or mutated without checking post-conditions.

Comment: @KarlNicoll `X` can be a proxxy.

Comment: @JerryCoffin it's not a mistake in this case. I am on a `&&` overload and more importantly I am returning a reference so RVO does not apply here. Retuning without `std:: move` here would be incorect.

Comment: @bolov: Umm...okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is that if you do not use references in the API parameters and return value, so you **may** risk to perform unneeded copies in both get/set operations ("MAY" because if you use the optimizer your compile will probably be able to avoid these copies).

I will write it as:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    X x_;
public:
    void x(const X &value) { x_ = value; }
    const X &x() const { return x_; }
};
```

This will keep the **const correctness**, that is a very important feature of C++, and it's compatibile with older C++ versions (the other answer requires c++11).

You can use this class with:

```
Foo f;
X obj;
f.x(obj);
X objcopy = f.x(); // get a copy of f::x_
const X &objref = f.x(); // get a reference to f::x_
```

I find the use of get/set superfluous both with _ or camel case (ie getX(), setX()), if you do something wrong the compiler will help you sort it out.

If you want to modify the inner Foo::X object, you can also add a third overload of x():

```
X &x() { return x_; }
```

.. in this way you can write something like:

```
Foo f;
X obj;
f.x() = obj; // replace inner object
f.x().int_member = 1; // replace a single value inside f::x_
```

but I suggest you to avoid this except if you really need to modify very often the inner struct (X).

Answer (score -7):

Use some IDE for generating. CLion offers the option for inserting getters and setters based on a class member. From there you can see the generated result and follow the same practice.