# Classes and encapsulation in C++ (OOP)

Tags: c++, class, oop, encapsulation, member

We're doing classes in CPP at my course right now using OOP and Im a bit lost with them. I understand the whole process - I think, but I just cant seem to get it right. Im quite new at this so please go easy on me.

Basically, the whole premise for this assigned task is to create the following variables and classes:

1. Create a class named Triangle
2. Encapsulate a, b, c - the triangle side lengths
3. bool Set (double aa, double bb, double cc); - sets the values and returns true or false depending on whether a triangle based on those lengths is possible
4. double Perim(); - calculates the perimeter of the triangle.
5. double Area (); - calculates the triangle area.
6. bool isRect(); - checks whether this is a right-angle triangle.

I hope that makes sense?

Heres what I have so far:

main.cpp file (far from complete, this is just as a placeholder at the moment):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "triangle.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
  Triangle t;
  int aa, bb, cc;

  cout <<"Triangle side 1 - " <<endl;
  cin >> aa <<endl;
  cout <<"Triangle side 2 - ";
  cin >> bb <<endl;
  cout <<"Triangle side 3 - ";
  cin >> cc <<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Triangle.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Triangle.cpp"

using namespace std;

#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

class Triangle(){

private:
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;

  double Perim();
  double Area();
  bool IsRect();

public:
  Triangle();
  Triangle(int, int, int);
  bool set(double aa, double bb, double cc);
};

#endif
```

and Triangle.cpp file (with the formulas to calculate everything)

```
#include "Triangle.h"

  Triangle::Triangle(){
   a = b = c = 0;
   Perim = 0.0;
   Area = 0.0;
 }

 Triangle::Triangle(int aa, int bb, int cc){

 }

  double Triangle::Perim(){
    return a + b + c;
  }

  double Triangle::Area(){
    s = (a+b+c)/2;
    Area = SQRT(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c));
    return Area;
  }

  bool Triangle::isRect(){
    return (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c)) ? true : false; //---checks if this is a right angle triangle, and should return true or false.
  }

  bool Triangle::Set(double aa, double bb, double cc){
    a = aa;
    b = bb;
    c = cc;

        if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a){//if one of these criteria is false, then a triangle is not possible.
          return cout << "A triangle with these parameters is possible.";
        }
        else{
          return cout << "A triangle with these parameters is NOT possible.";
        }
}
```

Of course this is far from complete, but Im struggling to link everything together.
Im trying to get the Main.cpp file, when the person enters the values, that should be passed to other cpp file and calculations made, and once thats done, to return the values to Main cpp through objects (yet to be created).
If that makes sense?

Ive been trying to wrap my head around this for a few hours now and I just cant seem to get it right, was hoping someone here would point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for the messy code..

Comment: `#include "Triangle.cpp"` - why is *that* in your `Triangle.h` header file ?? Unrelated, `using namespace std;` is a *terrible* idea, especially in a header, and any instructor that says otherwise should be held to higher scrutiny. Even more accurately, there is no reason for it in your posted code. It gives you nothing.

Comment: `cin >> aa <<endl;` - this won't work.

Comment: This is not as focused a question as you are expected to post on StackOverflow. The problems in the shown code are divers and indicate a lack of very basic knowledge. All in all this is practically asking for a turorial in OOP - which is offtopic. Please start on a more basic level, if necessary a HelloWorld. Follow some tutorial.

Comment: `(((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c))` _a, b_ and _c_ are double, not integer, the probability it is true is very small. And `return (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c)) ? true : false;` is just `return (((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c));`

Comment: @bruno — and none of those parentheses are needed. <g>

Comment: Change `int aa, bb, cc;` to `double aa, bb, cc;` in main.

Comment: "I'm trying to get the Main.cpp file ..."  there is no try, just do. Do a brief google review about 'stubs', or maybe c++ stubs. Use stubs as your 'first' attempt  at how your main will connect to and use the other code you have started.  Imagine data flow from and to the main and parts, then add details to stubs to document your favorite ideas.  Then implement, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an acceptable start. But there are a couple of issues here.

#### Let's go through the header first:

You need to get rid of the `#include` of a cpp file. You should only include headers in a header.  And better limit yourself to the headers really required by the code in the header. For instance, `<iostream>` is not really needed for the class definition.  So move this include to the cpp where it is needed.

You also need to get rid of the `using` clause: this should be used in cpp, and not in headers, because it causes the file including the header to ignore that another namespace is imported, which could later on create conflicts (in larger projects).   More advices on how to use headers [here](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1995).

Then a `Triangle` is a class and not a function.  So you have to define it with `class Triangle { ... };` and not `class Triangle() {...};`

I also would expect the following member functions to be public:

```
double Perim();    // These are definitively of interest for users of Triangles
double Area();
bool IsRect();
```

#### Now to the implementation

First, you need to avoid the confusion between member variables and member functions:

```
  Triangle::Triangle(){
   a = b = c = 0;
   // Perim = 0.0;   // NO !! Perim() is a function, you cannot assign a value to it
   // Area = 0.0;
 }
```

Then you need to declare the variables that you use:

```
 double Triangle::Area(){
    auto s = (a+b+c)/2;                // because s deosn't exist
    return std::sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));   // sqrt requires include <cmaths>
                                       // multiplication must be explicit.  
  }
```

Then you can just return a boolean expression.  No need to be more explicit:

```
bool Triangle::isRect(){
    return ((a*a) + (b*b)) == (c*c); 
  }
```

Finally,  your set function needs some rework:  you have to return `true` or `false`.  You better do not use `cout` in the return statement, but before returning.  Last but not the least, you must perform the test of validity before you assign the member variables.

#### Finally to main()

Input and output stream are different things.  So do not try `<<endl` on cin !

Once the input work,  you can use `t.set(...)` to use the values entered by the user to change t.

If the `t.set(...)` returns true, you can display the result of the functions. For example:

```
 cout << "Area: " << t.Area()<<endl;
```

If the result is false, then better inform the user that you can't do no more things with such a triangle.

I suppose that you know for the compilation how to compile the main.cpp and triangle.cpp together.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks ! Corrected !

Comment: Another error that is worth pointing out is the extra parentheses in `class Triangle(){`: it should be `class Triangle {`. This is easy to overlook, and it could give the OP some headaches.

Comment: @FabioTurati well spotted ! Thanks.  I've added your suggestion

Comment: @Christophe Thank you so much for your explanation! This has been very helpful. I am yet to update the code due to work, but this has been very detailed, much more than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good answer @Christophe. Didn't mean to duplicate your efforts! Feel free to parse over my answer and see if there's anything you wanted to add to yours to make a single most-complete answer, if you want.

Comment: @xoorath Thanks for the compliment. No problem about the duplication: it takes time to write such detailed answers and sometimes it's only when posting it and refreshing the screen that similarities are noticed. And yours is also very comprehensive. They can stay alongside to show that there is a consensus, and show the different arguments :-)

Answer (score 2):

## 1) Include header files, not cpp files!

**Remove:**

```
    #include "Triangle.cpp"
```

**reason:**

cpp files are what gets compiled. They depend on header files, not the other way around.
headers can depend on other headers, that happens a lot actually. but they shouldn't ever depend on a cpp file.

## 2) Wrap headers in ifndef/define blocks.

**Move:**

`#ifndef TRIANGLE_H` and `#define TRIANGLE_H` to the top of the file above everything else.
Stylistically you may want to comment what the file does above the ifndef/define block instead of under

**Example:**

```
    // This is the triangle header file! Here is where I describe it.
    #ifndef TRIANGLE_H
    #define TRIANGLE_H
    // TODO: Put the includes here
    // TODO: Put your class here
    #endif
```

**Reason:**

In C++ you can think of the line: `#include <iostream>` as copy-pasting the contents of the iostream file overtop of that line.
So when you #include "triangle.h" in both main.cpp and triangle.cpp, you're describing what the triangle class will look like
to each of those cpp files. main.cpp needs to know so it can create and use a triangle, and triangle.cpp needs to know so it can
implement the functions in Triangle correctly.

If you include a file twice, that file is effectively copy-pasted twice. Normally that would be re-defining its contents, which
would be a compile error. What the ifndef/define block does is say "hey, if TRIANGLE_H isn't already defined, this is the first
time it's been included. So go ahead and define TRIANGLE_H, along with all the file contents. The next time triangle.h is included
we'll see that TRIANGLE_H is already defined and we skip right by the contents of that header, instead of re-defining what a 
Trinagle is.

The reason I suggest you move it to the top, is you're including iostream, triangle.cpp (we talked about that part already) and
using namespace std every time triangle.h is included. There's no need for that.

## 3) Fix the triangle class declaration

**Change:**

```
    class Triangle(){
```

to

```
    class Triangle {
```

**Reason:**

You're close! but you're confusing the syntax of declaring a constructor with the syntax of declaring a class.

## 4) Make functions you intend to use outside of Triangle public.

**Move:**

the "public:" access specifier above `double Perim();`

**Reason:**

If you want to call the methods: Perim, Area and IsRect from main.cpp (or from anywehre but the inside of the triangle class!) 
you'll need those methods to be public.

You might be tempted to make everything public, but it's bad form - and your instructor specifically said "encapsulate a, b, c".
You can google the encapsulation design pattern to understand why. I won't get into it here.

## 5) Fill out your triangle constructor

**See the method:**

```
    Triangle::Triangle(int aa, int bb, int cc)
```

**Changes:**

- In the header file you don't give the three parameters names. This isn't an error, but it's weird. 
  You should probably give those parameters names.
- In your other constructor (the one without parameters) you show that you know how to assign a, b, and c a value!
  Go ahead and assign them values in this method.
- Consider if you actually want to use `int` as the types of the parameters. 
  You're storing the side lengths as doubles but you're providing them to the constructor as ints. This isn't an error, but it's weird.

## 6) Fix the body of the Set method.

**See the method:**

```
    Triangle::Set(double aa, double bb, double cc)
```

**Note:**

Remember a method is an exchange. You provide it with it's parameters, it does some work and it returns to you some value (unless it 'returns' void).
Your method is asking for 3 doubles, and returning a bool. If you're returning a bool, you're agreeing to give back a true or false value.
Here you're tring to return whatever cout << "..."; returns. That doesn't sound like what you want (even if it compiles). You don't care about what cout returns, right?

**Changes:**

Don't cout anything from this function. Just return true if a triangle is possible, and false if it's not possible.
You can cout whatever you want from where Set is being called from.

## 7) Encapsulate a, b, c.

You've made a b and c private. That's half of encapsulation. 
Your instructor **probably** wants you to write a getter and setter for these variables in Triangle.

**Example:**

```
    double Triangle::GetA() {
        return a;
    }

    void Triangle::SetA(double aa) {
        a = aa;
    }
```

I'll leave it as an exersize to do the rest.

## 8) Using your Triangle in main.cpp

If you take your local variable `t`, you can call functions on it like so:

```
    t.SetA(1.1);
    cout << t.GetA() << endl; // will print 1.1

    double theValueOfA; // local variable
    theValueOfA = t.GetA(); // store the result of GetA in our new variable

    cout << theValueOfA << endl; // will also print 1.1
```

With that information, after you're done your calls to cin to get the user inputs, do the following:

- create a boolean variable to store the result of set, we'll use this later.
- call the Set function on t, providing the 3 lengths the user inputted. Store the return of Set in our boolean.
- Write an if statement. Check if the value of that boolean is true. If it is, print "A triangle with these parameters is possible.", otherwise print "A triangle with these parameters is NOT possible."
- If your assignment requires you to do anything else or anything different, such as printing the result of Perim, Area and isRect, do that!

Comment: 1) compilers have optimizations that depend on the include guard to be the first thing in a header. I suggest you move your comments after the include guard. 2) For the ctor you should (strongly) suggest initializer lists. 3) If you create setters and getters for a private data member that don't do anything else but to get and set it that is a code smell, you should ask yourself if you really need a private data member. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters

Comment: @bolov 1) Which compiler would care about that? 2) To each their own teaching style, I wouldn't bring that up with a first year student. 3) Question for the student: what does your prof want? Once you know how to encapsulate, you can decide when to. I also wouldn't bring up const correctness to a first year student, but again to each their own teaching style.

Comment: 1) compilers do all sorts of things some consider to be... unnatural. 2,3) That is an age-old question. How much complexity should you protect the student from? Personally I'd bring in `const` correctness early because of the large number of problem families it eliminates. It's practically vaccination for your code.

Comment: @xoorath Thank you so much for this detailed explanation! To answer your question - unfortunately due to some problems our school replaced our prof. in the 2nd semester and to put it bluntly, he's very vague about everything hence my confusion I suppose. He didnt say exactly what he wants, he just gave us the list that I provided above as a guide and thats all..

Again, thank you so much for your explanation. And everyone else for contributing, this was much more than I was expecting.

Comment: @user4581301 I know more than your average bear about what c++ compilers are up to. I've just never witnessed having a comment above an ifndef block cause assembly to be generated any differently. I'd be surprised if this has been a real issue in the past 20 years; and actually shocked if it's an issue in any modern compiler version.

That's why I ask, hoping to be proven wrong, if I am.

Comment: @B.Baxter Happy to help!

Comment: Also an excellent answer, and very structured. I didn't address the second constructor in my answer because the setter ensures that triangle is always valid. To ensure consistency, so shall the second constructor do as well. The question is then what to do if the constructor arguments are invalid: keep default, allow invalid setting or raise an exception ? I thought OP should best discuss with the instructor to clarify.