# How to update the attributes of an object?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, member

I have an `Aircraft` class. I want to update the aircraft object's attributes in a loop (each one second).

How do I update these attributes without creating a new object? Should I use a pointer? My goal: update aircraft information every one second

My code:

```
class Aircraft
{
public:
    unsigned int altitude, speed, direction;

    Aircraft(unsigned int aAltitude, unsigned int aSpeed, unsigned int aDirection) 
    {
        altitude = aAltitude;
        speed = aSpeed;
        direction = aDirection;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //aircraft's initial values
    Aircraft myAircraft(0, 10, 345); 
    //Initial values should are printed 
    cout << myAircraft.altitude + "," + myAircraft.speed + "," + myAircraft.direction << endl; //print initial values

    //In this loop new values for altitude, speed and direction should be assigned
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //aircraft's new values
        Aircraft myAircraft(new altitude, new speed, new direction);

        //print updated attributes
        cout << myAircraft.altitude + "," +
                myAircraft.speed "," myAircraft.direction
             << endl << endl; //print new values
    }
}
```

The result should look like this: (The values don't matter)

```
0, 10, 345
0, 30, 345
0, 60, 345
0, 100, 345
0, 150, 345
300, 180, 345
700, 220, 345
2000, 250, 345
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I update these attributes without creating new object?

Create an `Aircraft` outside the loop and using [*setter* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters)(suggest make the class resources as `private`) of the class, to set each attribute inside the class.

> Should I use a pointer?

To the give explanation, decently **NOT**, as you just want to print each update in the class attributes, there is no need of dynamic memory allocations.

Regarding printing the elements each time after the updating, normal C++ convention is to *[overload `operator<<`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)*, which makes you conveniently write:

```
std::cout << aircraft_object;
```

A sample code would look like this: **([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XoCPvYm91vPQiwrR))**

```
#include <iostream>

using uint32 = unsigned int;
class Aircraft /* final */
{
private: // private attributes
    uint32 altitude, speed, direction;

public:
    // provided default arguments, so that default-construction is possible
    Aircraft(uint32 aAltitude = 0, uint32 aSpeed = 0, uint32 aDirection = 0)
        : altitude{ aAltitude }
        , speed{ aSpeed }
        , direction{ aDirection }
    {}
    // provide setters
    void setAltitude(const uint32 alti) noexcept { altitude = alti; }
    void setSpeed(const uint32 sp) noexcept { speed = sp; }
    void setDirection(const uint32 dir) noexcept { direction = dir; }
    // non-member function(s): operator<< overload
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aircraft& obj) noexcept;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aircraft& aircraft) noexcept
{
    return out << aircraft.altitude << ", " << aircraft.speed
                                    << ", " << aircraft.direction << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Aircraft aircraft_obj{}; // constructed with intial values {0, 0,0}

    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        uint32 alti, sp, dir;
        // get the user inputs
        std::cin >> alti >> sp >> dir;
        // set the attributes
        aircraft_obj.setAltitude(alti);
        aircraft_obj.setSpeed(sp);
        aircraft_obj.setDirection(dir);
        // print out the object
        std::cout << aircraft_obj;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**:

```
0 10 345
0 30 345
0 60 345
```

**Output**:

```
0, 10, 345
0, 30, 345
0, 60, 345
```

Comment: line 21: "
// non-member function(s): operator<< overload
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Aircraft& obj) noexcept; "

can you explain what this line of code does? I am a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: @claridade Did you read the link provided? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019. It declares an output stream `operator<<` for the class `Aircraft`  as a `friend` function(which are non-member functions). As I mentioned in the answer, that helps you to write simply `std::cout << aircraft_obj;`, which is a more convenient way of doing, rather typing whole things again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily modify non-const object values by using the `.` operator.

```
myAircraft.altitude  = newAltitude;
myAircraft.speed     = newSpeed;
myAircraft.direction = newDirection;

cout << myAircraft.altitude << ", " << myAircraft.speed << ", " << myAircraft.direction << '\n';
```

P.S. It's a very bad practice to print strings by concatenating them with `+`.
Instead, use the `<<` operator as shown above.

In your case, the code is not even valid since you're trying to add a number with a string. The logically correct way to do what you intended would be to convert the number into a string first `to_string(myAircraft.altitude) + ", "`.

Also, avoid using `endl` since it unnecessarily flushes the buffer. The benefits can be seen here: [Benchmark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqQOEZYVJQ).

Comment: _"It's a very bad practice to print strings by concatenating them with +"_ In that case it's not _bad practice_, but totally wrong. Numeric values and strings cannot be concatenated anyways.

Comment: Edited the answer to include your insight.