# How to define an graph of classes in C++ (field types, getters and setters)

Tags: java, c++, getter-setter

I am trying to figure the correct approach on how to write fields as well as getter and setter methods in C++ for classes that represent independent entities and form a graph or network of objects.

Keeping things simple, Lets say that we want to write the equivalent code in C++ of the following class in Java.

```
public class Person {

    private String name; // 1
    private Address address; // 2
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>(); // 3

    // 1
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    // 2
    public Address getAddress() { return address; }
    private void setAddress(Address address) { this.address = address; }

    // 3
    public List<Account> getAccounts() { return accounts; }
}

class Address { ... }
class Account { ... }
```

As you can see I have chosen the standard String type and 2 custom classes as member fields. That is because they are complex types. Besides the name field, the other 2 fields are chosen to demonstrate a typical a many-to-one relationship (person-adress) and one-to-many relationship (person-accounts).

In addition the String type in C++ (std:string) is a RAII type. It used typically in a literal way as it encapsulates the management of its actual value in the heap.

Now, it is not clear to me what would be the correct type definition for each field and how to expose them with getters and setters, while keeping each object's lifetime, in C++ as in the Java example above.

```
class Person {

    std::string _name;
    // address as pointer? reference? value? shared_ptr?
    // the same as above for the collection of accounts

    public:
    // appropriate getters, setters ?
}
```

NOTE 1: I am not interested in answers like "why are you doing this?" or "why do you want to do this?". The point of the question is to establish a clear understanding of how we can build a graph of objects in C++. There are plenty legitimate reasons and applications of this, such as designing a domain model, etc. So yes thanks for stinking to the point.

Comment: Well, how would you do it *without* getters and setters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write C++ getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters)

Comment: the best setters/getters are those that you don't write

Comment: @idclev please see note 1

Comment: Concerning _NOTE 2_: Then that's rather not a question about "getters and setters" but a question about proper life-time management and, maybe, about ownership of data and how to transfer it.

Comment: @Scheff You have a valid point. I will probably have to rephrase the question.

Comment: i second Scheff, in the code you posted lifetime is not an issue, everything is by value and in containers, if your question is not a duplciate you need to clarify what is your question

Comment: i might be wrong, but i sense some misunderstanding. What do you call "complex" type can be used with getters and setters just like an `int` or a `char`. `std::string` in C++ does not need special treatment for getters/setters. I guess large part of the confusion in the question comes from C++ and Java tags. The concept of lifetime is radically different in the two langauges

Comment: Even class instances may be assigned by value if they provide an assignment operator (or doesn't prevent the compiler default generated by one of its members). (Actually, `std::string` is nothing else than a class though it surely is created from a template.)

Comment: All this getter and setter nonsense does is circumvent encapsulation. A plain C-style `struct` would suffice. Really you should be thinking in terms of a constructor that sets most things up you need, and the odd "getter" style function and then only if it's necessary. Personally I strive for immutable objects if possible.

Comment: if you are coming from Java and think that managing lifetime is super complicated in c++ then you will like to hear that if done right all lifetimes is already managed automatically. You do not have to do anything extra. Complications only come when you ask for. Forget about pointers or references as members (until you really need them) then what is left to decide is covered by the duplicate: you can either return by value or by reference from the getter

Comment: As the original question failed to express clearly the intention, I rephrased the entire question and title to reflect precisely the purpose of defining and exposing fields of composite types in a graph or network of objects. You are welcome to re evaluate your comments - but please respect the NOTE above.

Comment: @Bathsheba Are you definite about this? Here are briefly some of the reasons of why people use access methods as a means of implementing the property of encapsulation. 1. They provide access to data that we need to expose in a  controlled manner (read, write, read and write). 2. They hide the implementation details from the client. 3. Provide a uniform API for exposing necessary information.

Comment: @DimitriosMenounos: Yes I'm quite sure. Adding getters and setters willy-nilly has nothing to do with creating an API. By the way, you should return `const&` types for your "getters" - but that sort of comment is really for the answers section.

Comment: to my understanding, encapsulation is about seperating data (private) and behaviour (the public api), if all the "behaviour" of a class is to grant access to its data then there is no need for encapsulation in the first place

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is the kind of discussion I wanted to avoid with the NOTE remark. The question is specific, how something can be done, not whether someone agrees with the approach or not. And this is because I know where these discussions lead - to nowhere.

Comment: the whole discussion about getters and setters is irrelevant for the quesiton if you take out the part that is already covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @idclev463035818 If you want, nevertheless, an answer see my response to Bathseba. There are perfectly valid reasons for access methods. I will add here that simply by following the single responsibility principle, inevitably we end to having to expose state, though in a controller manner. Consider for example, a domain model such as of the question above and several modules, GUI, XML serialization, JSON serialization, etc. Either you combine all responsibilities in the same class or expose structure, again in a controlled manner. A domain model IS the structure and it NEEDS to be reusable.

Comment: all that still does not explain what part of your getter/setter question is not covered in the proposed duplicate. I am not trying to convince you that setters and getters are not nice, I am trying to convince you that your question could be improved ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Actually, the proposed answer is pretty good. The only issue I have is that it is limited in scope. It covers only class members that are defined literally. It doesn't cover class members of reference type (smart pointer). It also doesn't cover collections. And since this is C++ declarations are not obvious. After researching the issue, I have found many good information here: https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/. I think I will write my own answer for my question sometime later on.

Comment: it doesnt mention them because for getters and setters it doenst matter if it is a refernce or a collection. What matters is discussed in said answer. Why do you think a getter for a `std::vector` needs to be any different than a getter for eg an `int` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am happy that you mention that. How do you write lets say a getter for a vector of something? Do you return a reference to the vector or value?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are conflating different things. I'll ignore the part of getters and setters for a moment...

> // address as pointer? reference? value? shared_ptr?

If you want a `std::string` then you use a `std::string`. If you want an `Adress` then you use an `Adress`. If you want a value then you use a value.There is no indication in your code that you need anything else. Most lifetimes are mangaged automatically in C++ (and deterministically in constrast to Java).

I am not perfectly certain but I guess a good replace for `ArrayList` is a `std::vector`. However, don't confuse them to be the same or even similar. An `ArrayList<whatever>` contains Java `Object`s while a `std::vector<std::string>` does contain acutal `std::string`s. Values.

```
struct Adress {
    std::string city;
};
struct Account {
    std::string password;
};

struct Person { 
    std::string _name;
    Adress adress;
    std::vector<Account> accounts;
};
```

This is all you need to correctly manage lifetime of the objects. Destructors are called automatically.

For passing parameters to setters and returning values from getters you can look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing). However, that part of the guidelines can be a bit overwhelming and basically all you need to know to get started with getters and setters you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The issue with this however, besides the omission of getter & setter definition which is an important aspect of the question, is that this is *an* object but not a graph of objects. As I see it, no other person can share the same address and no account share the same person. Thus it is not equivalent with the Java version I posted on top. You can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DimitriosMenousnos ok I think I finally understand what you want to ask. You should read about ownership. The important question is: Who owns what? If a `Person` owns its `Account`s then a `std::vector<Account>` is perfectly fine. For things that are shared between many you want to look at smart pointers, eg `std::shared_ptr<Adress>` if adresses can be shared between persons. Maybe I'll edit the answer, but honestly I think the question still could be much more clear. What to use for members and how to write getters and setters for them are really two seperate questions