# Is there any rule against putting more than one parameter in a mutator?

Tags: c++, conventions, mutators

I need my mutator to call a different function in my constructor and another function anytime after that, so I was thinking of putting a bool as a second parameter to differentiate as follows:

```
void SetName(const char* name, bool init)
{
     init ? this(name) : that(name);
}
```

Is this against convention or anything? Should I use two separate mutators instead?

Comment: no, there is nothing against having more parameters. However the form of getters and setters is idiomatically different in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615363/how-to-write-c-getters-and-setters

Comment: Be aware that Boolean arguments are confusing at the call site. Consider `enum class Field { a, b };` so the call looks like `foo.SetName(“baz”, Field::b);` rather than `foo.SetField(“baz”, true);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to make a mistake which can instead be prevented at compile-time. For example:

```cpp
Example example;
example.SetName("abc", true); // called outside the constructor, `init == true` anyway
```

To prevent such situations, just replace your

```cpp
struct Example {
    Example() { SetName("abc", true); }
    void SetName(const char* name, bool init) { init ? foo(name) : bar(name); }
};
```

with

```cpp
struct Example {
    Example() { foo("abc"); }
    void SetName(const char* name) { bar(name); }
};
```

Testing:

```cpp
Example example; // calls the for-the-constructor version
example.SetName("abc"); // calls the not-for-the-constructor version
example.SetName("abc", true); // obviously, doesn't compile any more
```